# What would be the correct way to organize this MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating a site similar to reddit where users can vote on links. Here are my 3 MySQL tables so far:

users

```
id | username | email | password
```

urls

```
id | url | description | submittedBy (references users.username) | upvotes | downvotes
```

comments

```
urlid (references url.id) | submittedBy (references users.username) | description
```

My question is; How would I document who upvotes and downvotes each url. I don't know if I need to

- Make a new table for each url and have each row have a user and whether they upvoted or downvoted
- Somehow store a list of what each specific user has voted on in the 'users' table
- Store a list in the 'url' table of all users who have upvoted/downvoted that url

Comment: "submittedBy (references users.username)" better to use users.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another table that stores the user id, the url id and the vote. I would use a simple u|d for up or down but you could use 0|1 or anything that you like.

```
votes
url_id | user_id | vote
```